# What is the difference between »aparcar« and »estacionar«?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, definiciones, verbos, diferencias-regionales

I have been revising vocabulary and I noticed that these two verbs have the same definition. Can someone, please clarify what the difference is.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[Source of information: Fundeu](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/aparcarestacionarparquear/)

> Tanto aparcar, estacionar como parquear tienen el mismo significado.
>   Estos tres verbos se usan en diferentes zonas hispanohablantes y las
>   tres formas son adecuadas.
>
> En Centroamérica y los países del norte de Sudamérica lo más habitual
>   es parquear en los parqueos, excepto en Colombia, donde se parquea en
>   el parqueadero. En estos países, también se utiliza estacionar en los
>   estacionamientos.
>
> En los países del Cono Sur (Argentina, Chile, Paraguay…) se usan
>   solamente el verbo estacionar y el sustantivo estacionamiento. Y en
>   otros, como Ecuador, se utilizan indistintamente parquear y
>   estacionar.
>
> Además, aparcar solo se usa en España, cuyo sustantivo es
>   aparcamiento.
>
> Así pues, son adecuadas estas frases encontradas en los medios de
>   comunicación: «Aparcar en la Via Augusta será de pago a partir de
>   hoy», «Mataró ofrece estacionar gratis en zona azul durante el verano»
>   y «Al ejecutarse la propuesta en aquellos lugares no se podrán
>   parquear automotores».

Ojo con la adaptación de la voz inglesa, usamos *parquear* y fácilmente podríamos escribir *parking*, pero la RAE recomienda *parquin* (sin g! aunque no creo que los letreros de muchas ciudades cambien).

> parquin. Adaptación gráfica propuesta para la voz inglesa parking,
>   ‘lugar destinado al aparcamiento de automóviles’. Su plural debe ser
>   párquines (→ plural, 1g): «El que ha salido en defensa de los
>   párquines ha sido el concejal de Seguridad, [...] que asegura [...]
>   que no hay ningún aparcamiento peligroso en la capital» (Cadena SER
>   [Esp., corpus oral] 3.11.96). Aunque, por su extensión, se admite el
>   uso del anglicismo adaptado, se recomienda usar con preferencia voces
>   españolas de sentido equivalente, como aparcamiento, en España:
>   «Caminó hacia su coche, situado en un aparcamiento cercano» (Millás
>   Desorden [Esp. 1988]); y, en América, según las zonas,
>   estacionamiento, parqueo, parqueadero y playa (de estacionamiento),
>   referida esta última, en especial, al situado en una explanada al aire
>   libre: «Estaba buscando el carro en el estacionamiento» (Aguilera
>   Pelota [Ec. 1988]); «Estaban estacionados en los parqueos de la
>   Presidencia» (Prensa [Nic.] 24.7.97); «El parqueadero de la Plaza de
>   Toros estaba ya repleto» (Gamboa Páginas [Col. 1998]); «Mientras
>   entraba a la playa de estacionamiento, verificaba [...] que el Dodge
>   había sido lavado» (VLlosa Tía [Perú 1977]).

Comment: Todas las terminaciones -ing en inglés se adaptan como -in en español: meeting → mitin, piercing → pirsin. No es nada de qué sorprenderse

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty related.

1. *aparcar* means you can leave your vehicle temporarily in a place. (Probably with people inside.)
2. *estacionar* means you can leave your vehicle, empty inside, and for a longer time.

But, I'd say the use is regional. I've seen on TV that people often use *aparcar* over *estacionar.*

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been going insane looking for a answer.

Comment: According to what I learnt during my driving lessons (which I took not too long ago), a "parada" means you are inside your car and for no longer than two minutes. You can make a "parada" in "doble fila", but you can't "aparcar" in "doble fila". On the other hand, "aparcar" is chiefly European Spanish and "estacionar" is more common in Spanish from Latin American, but both mean "to park", not to stop your car ("hacer una parada/detención"). See http://multasdetrafico.com.es/multas-aparcamiento for clarification and http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/aparcar for dialectical variations.

Answer (score 1):

Both are synonyms. 'Aparcar' its an anglicism (voice taken from the english) and 'estacionar' it's more correct. However both words are widely and interchangeably used nowadays. To my knowledge -as AlexBcn mentioned- 'aparcar' is most used in Spain, Colombia and Venezuela.
I disagree with Ustanak and the difference he made of both words. My experience is that they are quite the same. Both means that you park your car, stop the engine and get out of it for some time. 
'Parada', on the other hand, means that you just stop the car but not stop the engine. It's just while driving in a street, and you stop your car -say, because a red ligth-.
Hope this helps.

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna evidencia para designar *aparcar* como anglicismo?  *Aparcar* registra usos que significaban «dejar/parar/fijar en un lugar» (que es, efectivamente, lo que sigue significando) en el siglo XVII — muy antes del advenimiento de los coches— y vino de la palabra *parque*, que siendo franco (ja), es galicismo de *parc* y no anglicismo.